# How can I make a json array to a asp.net Multidimensional string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I sent an array of data using a json post to my asp.net controller like this::

….code here…..

```
 var data = [
  ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
   ];
```

code here……

```
   data: JSON.stringify({data: myData})
```

code here……

I’ve got this array that I would like to reformat to send to the database.
In the controller I use this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult tableData(String data){}
```

and get this:

```
 [[\"leaveBlank", \"Kia\", \"Nissan\",\"Totota\",null], [\”2008\”,10,11,12,13,null],     [\”2009\”,20,11,14,13,null],[null, null, null, null, null, null]]
```

I don’t know how to deal with the mix of escape sequences and commas.  How do I make it so that my array would be some sort of multidimensional array like in this case [4,5] so that I can access each element individually?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<object[]> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object[]>(jsonString);
```

Will do what you want. Because you have mixed types in the inner arrays you have to use `object` which sucks. If they were all strings or int's then you could change the array type and avoid a bunch of casts. By the way, my code is using json.NET. If you're not already using that for json serlialization/deserialization I highly recommend it.

Comment: I see the logics but I don't have a JsonConverter in the namespace when i search for it in the object browser.  Any idea how i can access JsonConvert?  Thanks.

Comment: @CloudyKooper that would be because you're not using json.NET. Download it via nuget or from their website ( http://james.newtonking.com/json ), add it as a reference, then add `using Newtonsoft.json` to the file.

Comment: So i now have access to Newtonsoft.Json but my version does not give me JsonConverter.Deserializer.  It does give me JsonConverter.DeserializeObject.  I then tried to use it like this:  List<object[]> myJson JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<ActionResult>(data); but it's the wrong sintax.  Any idea how i can work with the adeserializeObject? Thanks.

Comment: @CloudyKooper yeah sorry about that, I had the wrong method. I believe what I have there post edit will work. The reason what you have in the comment above is the wrong syntax is because the type you specify as `T` in `DeserializeObject<T>` is also the return type, so basically you're trying to assign an `ActionResult` to a reference of type `List<object[]>`

Comment: So now I'm trying this:  List<object[]> myJson= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object[]>>(data);  but no luck.

Comment: @CloudyKooper what do you mean by no luck? An exception is thrown? The result isn't what you're expecting?